# How to conditionally run a Databricks job from a notebook?

Tags: amazon-s3, conditional-statements, databricks, jobs, aws-databricks

I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally run a job (or a task in a job) from a Notebook. I would like the notebook to check a specific s3 location, look for a file, and do one of two things:

-If there are one or more files, run the job as usual
-If there are no files in the location, do not run the job and print a message saying the job will not run due to lack of file

I'm newer to Databricks, and while I know how to create and schedule jobs in the Jobs API, I'm not familiar with the Databricks API and tools like system.exit to orchestrate these types of tasks. Currently, the job in question will run end to end if there is no file, it just won't populate any downstream systems.

I had considerations to use the length of the results from an ls on the s3 location as the pivot for the conditional statement, but not sure if that'sthe best approach either. Appreciate any help!